# Repeat data on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that I'm building that I want to be able to change account names on the fly using Ajax. Everything works smoothly on the name change submission, however, on the second one, I get duplicated data, even though the function is relative to $(this). Here is an example of my console. It ends up overwriting the first submission somehow, and sends the second inputted name in for both the current account, and the previous account.

[image]

**index.html**

```
<a id="edit-name" number-data="+155512345678" phone-sid="example"></a>

$(document).on("click", "#edit-name", function(){
 var num = $(this).attr("number-data");
 var sid = $(this).attr("phone-sid");

 $(this).parent().parent().append('<div class="input-wrapper"><div class="input-field"><label for="name-change">Name</label><input id="name-change" type="text" class=""></div><a id="send-name" class="btn">send</a></div>');


    $(document).on("click", "#send-name", function(){
    var val = $(this).prev().children("#name-change").val();

     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'manage-account.php',
      data: {trackingNumber: num, newName: val, phoneSID: sid},
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
  });
 });
});
```

**manage-account.php**

```
$trackingNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['trackingNumber']);
$newName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['newName']);

echo "Tracking Number: ". $trackingNumber;
echo "Phone Name: ". $newName;
```

Comment: Binding click events inside of click events. Every click on the outside adds a new click event so they double up. Pull the second click out of the first...

Comment: Can I pass both num and sid as paramters on a click function?

Comment: Other problem is you assign multiple element with the same id. SO if you used a unique id, you would not have the issue.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? I have a label for my main input element that matches that elements ID, but thats all I can see.

Comment: You append the button. `<a id="send-name" class="btn">` So do it twice, you have two of them with the same id...

Comment: Right, but both the button and input element have different id's

Comment: Not when you bind multiple buttons... Each click you append a new button. so it has the same id as the last one.

Comment: I'm pulling the value you though relative to $(this) click though, right? $(document).on("click", "#send-name", function(){

var val = $(this).prev().children("#name-change").val();

Comment: make no difference if the check is looking for an id when you bind multiple elements to the same id.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on a solution? I thought by traversing the dom based on the location of $(this) was the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Bind two events separately, use data attributes

```js
var cnt = 0;
$(document).on("click", ".edit-name", function() {
  var anc = $(this);
  num = anc.data("number"),
    sid = anc.data("sid"),
    html = '<div class="input-wrapper">\
    <div class="input-field">\
    <label for="name-change' + cnt + '">Name</label>\
    <input id="name-change' + cnt + '" type="text" data-number="' + num + '" data-sid="' + sid + '">\
    </div>\
    <a class="send-name btn">send</a>\
    </div>';

  anc.closest(".out").append(html);

});

$(document).on("click", ".send-name", function() {
  var inp = $(this).prev().find("input");
  console.log(inp.val(), inp.data("number"), inp.data("sid"));
});
```

```css
.btn { border: 1px solid black; pointer: cursor; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="out">
  <div>
    <a class="edit-name" data-number="+155512345678" data-sid="example">xxx</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="edit-name" data-number="+3123213" data-sid="eeee">xxx</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="edit-name" data-number="+123123" data-sid="dddd">xxx</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and use data attributes.